# My Persistent Left Drawer doesn’t shrink the content at it’s right, Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I’m trying to create a persistent left drawer with React – Material UI, and I expect to have the content at the right shrunk when the drawer is open

But it doesn’t happen, I think it’s because the argument ‘open’ is not recognized:

[image]

I'm working with version 5.1.1

Why can I do?

Rafael

Comment: I upgraded de MUI version to 5.2.1, the error disappeared, but still no shrinking

Answer (score 0):

Check that your drawer imports from `@mui/material` are correct.

```
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
```

Comment: It's there ok...

Answer (score -1):

I already did it.

When copying the code for the persistent drawer from the Material UI page, it has the drawer and the page content all in the same component

I that is not your case, most likely, you do something like this:

```
const drawerWidth = 210;

// @ts-ignore
const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}`,
    ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
        }),
        marginLeft: 0
    })
}));

const MainPage = () => {
    const [ drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen ] = React.useState(false);
    const [ marginLeftWhenDrawerOpens, setMarginLeftWhenDrawerOpens ] = useState(0);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(true);
        setMarginLeftWhenDrawerOpens(drawerWidth);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(false);
        setMarginLeftWhenDrawerOpens(0);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <PersistentDrawerLeft drawerOpen={drawerOpen} closeDrawer={handleDrawerClose} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} />
            <Main
                // @ts-ignore
                open={drawerOpen}
                sx={{ marginLeft: `${marginLeftWhenDrawerOpens}px` }}
            >
                <Grid container direction="column">
                    <Grid item>
                        <MainPageHeader
                            openDrawer={handleDrawerOpen}
                            marginLeftWhenDrawerOpens={marginLeftWhenDrawerOpens}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item container>
                        <Grid item xs={1} />
                        <Content />
                        <Grid item xs={1} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Footer />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

And, of course, MainHeader adjusts its marginLeft according to marginLeftWhenDrawerOpens

The // @ts-ignore is there because I get an error, but things are still working

Rafael